# ElasticSearch symbiosis of fuzzy search with prefix search

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

I want to create a simple full text search with fuzziness and with prefix search. What I mean - I have entity `Tags`, it has column `name`, nothing special. For example I have names `Animal` and `Animal Portrait`.
When I try this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": {
        "query": "animal",
        "fuzziness": "AUTO"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

everything works great. Fuzzinnes works good too. But this query doesn't work with prefixes. When I try to search `anim` - I get nothing. Does elastic have some ability to create fuzzinnes search with prefix search in one query? Or perhaps there are some other variants to make fulltext search in fuzzy way and with prefix search? Or at least another way (not fuzzy) + prefixes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subfield with a custom analyzer based on [edge-n-grams tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html). This way `anim` will be one of the tokens and you can use fuzziness against it too.